# How to get screen display metrics in application class

Tags: android, metrics

If I put this in some activity class it works perfectly but, when I put it in my App class the method `getWindowManager()` can not be found. Is there some way to get the WindowManager in app class?

My app class is defined like this:

```
public class myApp extends Application {
```

and in on create method I have this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm); 
int width = dm.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here, [Context.getResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29)

```
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); 
int densityDpi = dm.densityDpi;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also try this:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 3):

**hope this will work for you**

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int pxWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int pxHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

> With Context -

```
context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
```

> Without Context use -

```
Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels // but this doesn't work well on foldables
```

Note : `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);` returns `void` in the new API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Log.e("", "" + display.getHeight() + " " + display.getWidth());
```

Comment: You can`t get getWindowManager in Application class.

Comment: @NiteshKhosla could you point any doc showing us that Application class contains a method getWindowManager() ? I can't find it here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score -1):

```
final DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;

getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .8), (int) (height * .5));
```