# Setting an ImageView to a portion of screen height inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-layout-weight

I have this ImageView I want cropped to occupy no more than 1/3 the screen size. I have used the following layout using layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight where needed but the ImageView keeps taking more height than it should. If I replace the ScrollView with LinearLayout everything falls into place as it should. My guess is this is because the ScrollView has unlimited height... How can I still force the ScrollView to honor the real layout height of its parent and achieve what I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
            >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                    android:text="Text1"
                />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:text="Text2"
                />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:text="Text3"
                />
                <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/textview4"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                   android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                   android:singleLine="false"
                   android:text="Text4"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's how it looks like:

[image: Layout Final]

Answer (score 1):

A `Scrollview` has "infinite height" according to the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

So, "1/3" height really has no meaning - the LinearLayout will simply occupy whatever height it needs/wants/can within a Scrollview.

if you want a View to be 1/3 of the screen size, but you also want it to scroll, then use `DisplayMetrics` to calculate the height of your screen and then layout elements accordingly. (Likewise, if you want the "top" portion to be 2/3 of the screen height, do the same.)

See this post:

[How to get screen display metrics in application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114436/how-to-get-screen-display-metrics-in-application-class)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ImageView, try this

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```