# I can not deal with non-standard resolution

Tags: android, android-resolution

I have design for my project. It for Nexus 6 with resolution 1440px x 2560px and 493 ppi. My design - 1440px x 2560px.

I know that:

```
ldpi    120 dpi
mdpi    160 dpi
tvdpi   213 dpi
hdpi    240 dpi
xhdpi   320 dpi
xxhdpi  480 dpi
xxxhdpi 640 dpi
```

I have - 493 ppi. what's this? I have a button size 100x50 pixels on the design. 
how many dpi need button to look as well as in the design?

Comment: Only one solution,try diff sizes and run in your phone.Check whichever seems to be good,use that size finally.

Comment: I'm doing. but the rest of the phone is already on display in the dpi and everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps: [Getting Your Apps Ready for Nexus 6 and Nexus 9](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)

> **Nexus 6**
>
> **Screen**
>
> The Nexus 6 boasts an impressive 5.96” Quad HD screen display at a
>   resolution of 2560 x 1440 (493 ppi). This translates to ~ 730 x 410 dp
>   (density independent pixels).
>
> **Check your assets**
>
> It has a quantized density of **560 dpi**, which falls in between the
>   xxhdpi and xxxhdpi primary density buckets. For the Nexus 6, the
>   platform will scale down xxxhdpi assets, but if those aren’t
>   available, then it will scale up xxhdpi assets.

EDIT:

Consider this line

> 2560 x 1440 (493 ppi). This translates to ~ 730 x 410 dp (density
>   independent pixels)

It implies the scaling factor is 2560/730 = 1440/410 ~ 3.5

For a screen of width 410 and height 730 in dp, if you want to specify a button of half the screen width in dp, the width should be 410/2 = 205 dp which translates to 717px = 205*3.5 (width in dp * scaling factor)

A button of size 100px x 50px would translate to 28 x14 dp (100/3.5 * 50/3.5) on a 410 x 730 dp screen size.

Comment: excellent article. that's cool. but the question is the same in another. How do I specify the correct spacing, height, buttons etc? if I point out in the dpi all drawn crooked

Comment: i have some problems with LG G3 mini (294 dpi)

Comment: I feel I was stupid. my design 1440x2560 - xxxhdpi. 100px(xxxhdpi) = 25dpi. 50px(xxxhdpi) =12.50dpi. I have these values and they work on all phones except the nexus 6 and LG G3 mini. if I point 28 x14 dp then the rest will be all crooked phones

Comment: you can create a separate dimens.xml file for the two phones that are causing a problem

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do it?

Comment: Read more about the file here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension - create different dimens xml say at res/values/dimens.xml for normal values and res/values/sw400dp-xxxhdpi/dimens.xml (the smallest width of the device, taking the minimum of the landscape and portrait widths is 400dp or wider in xxxhdpi) for nexus 6

Answer (score 1):

If you are genuinely concerned about proper display resolution (which it sounds like you are) then you should **never** rely on the generic folders. The folders are there for generalized purposes - not for customized or high value display.

You should use `displayMetrics` to measure the screen size and select the appropriate asset, or even do customized image scaling. There are a lot of resources around this set of properties, but essentially it allows you to address the issue you are facing: set appropriate margins, padding, resolution, layout, etc. for a highly customized display.

Here are the docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

And then some "simple" implementations of getting the metrics:
[How to get screen display metrics in application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114436/how-to-get-screen-display-metrics-in-application-class)

[getting the screen density programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)